# Scroll down Chat on set time but deactivate on user interaction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm writing a web Chat system to permit user to write a message to their friend but I have a problem scrolling down the new messages using jquery.

I have these files: 
`messages.php` where I store the form for submitting and view the messages;
`chatupd.js` executes post and get messages and refresh the div every 'x' seconds;
`post_updmsg.php` Prints messages to database; 
`get_updmsg.php` Gets the latest messages from database;

But the only files needed for this question are the first two:

`messages.php`

```
<div class='chatContainer'>
    <div class='chatHeader'>
        <h3>Welcome <?php echo get_talkm3_nome(); ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class='chatMessages'>
        <?php
include '../core/config.inc.php';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$id_usr_2 = $_SESSION['email'];
//Get Messages
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `chat_t3`");



$query->execute();

            //Fetch
while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id_usr_2 = $fetch['id_usr_2'];
$id_usr_1 = $fetch['id_usr_1'];
    $text = $fetch['text'];
    $date = $fetch['date'];
    if ($id_usr_1 == $_SESSION['email']){   
    echo "<li class='message_container'><div class='sender'>From - <b>".ucwords($id_usr_1)."</b> TO - ".ucwords($id_usr_2)."</b> - ".$text." ".ucwords($date)."</div></li> ";
    } else {
    echo "<li class='message_container'><div class='reader'>From - <b>".ucwords($id_usr_1)."</b> TO - ".ucwords($id_usr_2)."</b> - ".$text." -".ucwords($date)."</div></li> ";
}
}
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class='chatBottom'>
        <form action='#' onSubmit='return false;' id='chatForm'>
        <input type='hidden' id="id_usr_1" value="<?php echo get_talkm3_email() ?>"><br />
        <input type='text' id='id_usr_2' value="" placeholder="inserisci la mail del destinatario" />
        <input type='text' name='text' id='text' value='' placeholder='Type your message'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post'>
        </form>
        <br>

    </div>
</div>
```

`chatupd.js`

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', '#chatForm', function(){
        var id_usr_1 = $.trim($("#id_usr_1").val());
        var id_usr_2 = $.trim($("#id_usr_2").val());
        var text = $.trim($("#text").val());

        if (id_usr_1 != "" && id_usr_2 != "" && text != ""){
            $.post('../core/chat/post_updmsg.php', {id_usr_1: id_usr_1, id_usr_2: id_usr_2, text: text}, function(data){
                $(".chatMessages").append(data);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Data Missing");
        }
    });

    function getMessages (){
        $.get('../core/chat/get_updmsg.php', function(data){
            $(".chatMessages").html(data);
        });
    }

    setInterval(function(){
        getMessages();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Now, my questions are:

- How can I automatically scroll down the page to display latest message? But if the user wants to see the old messages and scroll up the page, prevent that after 'x' seconds they is redirected to the bottom of the page?
- If the user scrolls up the page and script to scroll down is blocked, how to reactivate it when user scroll down completely the page?

Comment: I googled a lot of guides, but i'm not so good using jquery and all i tried to do hasn't worked

Comment: Thank you Dave for your advices

Comment: (Offtopic) You're missing `<ul>` inside your DIV `.chatMessages`

Comment: I created several chat widgets, and invented this kind of UI where when you interact with the scrollable area > there will be no scroll. See this  answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457294/chat-app-scrollable-div-or-iframe and play with the demo. Is it a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the example to do what I need to do

Comment: No, is not a duplicate, I hope to solve the problem but I might need your help. And unfortunately I did not read your post before posting. More than anything I want ask in my case how to do.

Comment: Congratulations for your guide, is done very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other implementations there are two (nice) ways to achieve what you want.
The first is the one you want:

### Not at bottom (User scrolled up) > Lock scroll

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/birusi/8/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

If the user scrolls the messages > don't scrollToBottom at new message arrival:

```
var $chat = $(".chatMessages");
var chatHeight = $chat.innerHeight();
var c = 1;
var chatIsAtBottom = true;


function newMessage() {
  $chat.append("<li>This is message "+ (c++) +"</li>");
  if(chatIsAtBottom){
    $chat.stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $chat[0].scrollHeight - chatHeight
    },600);
  }
}

function checkBottom(){
  chatIsAtBottom = $chat[0].scrollTop + chatHeight >= $chat[0].scrollHeight;
}

$chat.scrollTop( $chat[0].scrollHeight ).on("scroll", checkBottom);
setInterval( newMessage, 2000 );
```

- **Pros**: Other events will not mess with the current user-defined scroll position.
- **Cons**: In this example, while leaving the Messages scroll area you need to notify the user about "[New unread messages]" > that will on click scroll back to bottom.

### Hover/Focus on Comment-area > Toggle-lock scroll

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/birusi/7/edit)***

The other one is related to [this old post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457541/383904) that does:

If user hovers the messages area (Logically he's: 1. Scrolling, reading, copying some old text etc... interacting :) )  - than prevent scroll

```
var $chat = $(".chatMessages");
var chatHeight = $chat.innerHeight();
var c = 1;

function newMessage() {
  $chat.append("<li>This is message "+ (c++) +"</li>");
  if(!$chat[0].noScroll) {
    $chat.stop().animate({scrollTop: $chat[0].scrollHeight-chatHeight},600);
  }
}

$chat.hover(function() {
  return this.noScroll ^= 1;
});

$chat.scrollTop( $chat[0].scrollHeight );
setInterval( newMessage, 2000 );
```

- **Pros:** Straightforward UI
- **Cons:** It's cool and intuitive in most cases, but might be annoying if the user was i.e: copying a message from that scrolled board - on mouseleave the scroll-bottom might prevent the user from doing more actions on that exact scroll position.

Comment: Wow, your code worked very well, but, how to improve performance on scroll? It is very laggy on Mobile. I used  the first option. I tryed to delete the post below, but is still visible :(